# Pouchdb query() leaving out documents on emit()

Tags: react-native, couchdb, pouchdb

For some reason my filter is not working correctly. It was working fine a moment ago and then for some reason it stopped returning all of the templates and only started returning one of them.

Why might it be returning it twice but only giving me one?

I have the following code:

```
export async function testMe() {
    const company_id = await AsyncStorage.getItem('company_id');
    const device_db = new PouchDB(company_id, {});

    device_db.query(function(doc, emit){
        console.log(doc.type, doc._id, doc._rev);
        if(doc.type == 'template') {
            emit(doc._id, doc); 
        }
    }).then((result) => { 
        console.log("Returned", result);
    })
}
```

What is unexpectedly happening is this is what gets returned:

```
template template_1 18-5918af4c5370d9755d0bb8b6dcb21ea1
template template_2 19-8191dec49dfa8c1a2f03d752a193f09e
template template_3 39-74f3b82ce4a38a501810b5ff31efc593
undefined "dpbcab6843-2cdf-4d4c-87ae-286dcddaac22" "2-8f03f3127771dadd3c8f7beb3e827982"
undefined "dpdc6f6cd0-6c6d-4974-a166-b848a0217af4" "2-0eec1a8d925641aa8bf30e058e6515e7"
undefined "dpe1573a70-a281-4e15-a997-82d8bf8fabfa" "2-d3bbcb81344f61cc94459610695c6670"
template template_3 39-74f3b82ce4a38a501810b5ff31efc593
```

You can ignore the undefined, but what I am trying to show is look at what gets returned twice:

```
template template_3 39-74f3b82ce4a38a501810b5ff31efc593
```

In the `Returned` console.log(), this is the only thing that gets returned (the last template_3 piece of data, totally ignoring the other templates even though they are both type `template`):

```
{"total_rows":6,"offset":0,"rows":[{"key":"template_3","id":"template_3","value":{..}}]}
```

### Edit

It's getting even weirder. I just opened `template_2` and did a save (in Cloudant) and synced it with my device to update the `_rev` and now I get:

```
template template_1 18-5918af4c5370d9755d0bb8b6dcb21ea1
template template_2 20-c549fe868735ef0099b80f6668af611c
template template_3 39-74f3b82ce4a38a501810b5ff31efc593
undefined "dpbcab6843-2cdf-4d4c-87ae-286dcddaac22" "2-8f03f3127771dadd3c8f7beb3e827982"
undefined "dpdc6f6cd0-6c6d-4974-a166-b848a0217af4" "2-0eec1a8d925641aa8bf30e058e6515e7"
undefined "dpe1573a70-a281-4e15-a997-82d8bf8fabfa" "2-d3bbcb81344f61cc94459610695c6670"
template template_3 39-74f3b82ce4a38a501810b5ff31efc593
template template_2 20-c549fe868735ef0099b80f6668af611c
```

Which returns (leaving out template_3):

```
{"total_rows":6,"offset":0,"rows":[{"key":"template_2","id":"template_2","value":{..}}]}
```

### Edit 2

I added:

```
.catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
})
```

And get this: `{"status":409,"name":"conflict","message":"Document update conflict","error":true}`

However, I do the following an all `_conflict` arrays are empty:

```
device_db.allDocs({conflicts: true})
.then((data) => {
    for (let d of data.rows) {
        console.log(d.doc._conflicts);
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe temporary queries like this should have a key, otherwise the query would not know what documents you want to select. The example from [the PouchDb docs](https://pouchdb.com/guides/queries.html) is

```
db.query(function (doc, emit) {
  emit(doc.name);
}, {key: 'foo'}).then(function (result) {
  // found docs with name === 'foo'
}).catch(function (err) {
  // handle any errors
});
```

so that documents with a "name" field equal to "foo" are returned by the query. In your query the key appears to be undefined. This might explain the odd results you are getting?